# Get the count of number of contacts while analysing a .pst file in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have to analyse several .pst files and enter the sender,receiver details,subject etc into a MySQL database (which contains a list of default contacts as well) which is working fine. I also have to get the count of total known contacts and unknown contacts. For unknown contact count, I can get it using the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery () but how do i get the list of known contacts (or all the contacts in the .pst file).
I tried having a boolean variable and using it as a counter but since I need to flush my contact list , the value is lost.

```
foreach (Contact c in contact)
{
    if (senderMailId.ToLower().Equals(c.getName().ToLower()))
    {
        id_sender = c.getId();
        b = true;
        c.setKnown(true);
    }
}

// if contact is not there insert into contact
if (!b)
{
    if (senderName.Contains(","))
    {
        string[] separators = { "," };
        String[] s = senderName.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        senderFName = s[0];
        senderLName = s[1];
    }
    id_sender = InsertToContact(senderFName, senderLName, senderMailId, 0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I do not understand you correctly but why don't you rewrite the second block to an else block and put it inside the foreach loop?

Comment: I am setting the flag in the for else loop by going through the existing contacts. But the problem is when the same contact is encountered again the counter is incremented which should not happen .

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you be more specific about what known and unknown contacts are?

Comment: I have a  database in which I update the contacts as and when I get them from the .pst files. So when I read a new .pst file, it may have contacts previously found in the database or completely new ones.